# 401 Error Document Within Protected Directory

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd, errordocument

I have an error document (symlink actually) in a protected directory. I want to use my custom error page but the 401 error isn't working due to it being a private directory. How can I solve this?

Here's my .htaccess right now

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile /home1/user/public_html/.htpasswd 
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding this to my .htaccess

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/error.php$" allow_all
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow_all
Satisfy any